# Вернуть часть предложения из текста

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть текст вида:

```
Результат запроса
По Вашему запросу о действительности паспорта РФ 0001 № 784596 получен ответ о том, что данный паспорт «Cреди недействительных не значится».
Параметры запроса
Поиск был произведен по следующим, указанным Вами параметрам:

Серия паспорта: 0001

Номер паспорта: 784596
СООБЩИТЬ ОБ ОШИБКЕ
ДРУГОЙ ЗАПРОС
©2021 Главное управление по вопросам миграции МВД России
```

Я хочу вернуть строку вида:

```
Результат запроса
По Вашему запросу о действительности паспорта РФ 0001 № 784596 получен ответ о том, что данный паспорт «Cреди недействительных не значится».
```

Моя попытка:

```
preg_match_all('/По Вашему(.*?)+\n/', $data, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Как из текста получить только определенную часть текста?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```php
if (preg_match('/По Вашему[^.]*/u', $data, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
// => По Вашему запросу о действительности паспорта РФ 0001 № 784596 получен ответ о том, что данный паспорт «Cреди недействительных не значится»
```

См. [пример кода на PHP](https://3v4l.org/tWVQu) и [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Csh0Is/1).

`[^.]*` находит ноль и более символов, отличных от `.`.